# Secure Way To Store Credentials in Front-End Tests

Tags: security, webdriver-io

I am currently writing automated tests using webdriverio for my current project. The thing is the company Im currently working is so strict with security so putting the credentials in the spec file is a big no. This project we are working is an internal tool and the authentication is using the employees' gmail accounts which is also the authentication being used across all services being used by the company. Can someone suggest other ways how to store credentials securely that my spec file can access. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just posted [a video about this on YouTube](https://youtu.be/DiaFdOtUoo8). Granted, it's about storing Cloud Selenium Service credentials, but the same ideas apply.

Here are the three options I cover:

- Pass in credentials via the command line
- Store the credentials in a 'secrets.js' file that isn't part of your shared code and load it via Node's `require` system
- Store the credentials in environment variables and use `process.env` to access them.